# Eliminate reflections on pulse signal transformer

Tags: rf, transformer, impedance-matching, signal-integrity, termination

I am trying to isolate an RLC ringdown signal via an [RF signal transformer](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ADTT1-6+.pdf) but I'm having trouble maintaining the signal integrity through the transformer. Below is the simple schematic describing my system:

[image]

The ringdown is coming from a capacitor discharge which drives the current \$I_p\$ through the shunt resistor \$R1\$. The current is on the order of a few kA so the ringdown signal typically has an amplitude of about 10V and a frequency of 1.25 MHz. Here is an LTSpice simulation of what it looks like:

[image: LTSpice Ringdown]

All I really care about is the first two cycles since I am using compactors to extract the needed data such as the rise time, amplitude and frequency. I ordered some samples of the [ADTT1-6+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ADTT1-6+.pdf) RF signal transformer and made a makeshift simple prototype board using copper clad pcb and an exacto knife. Here is the layout:

[image: Proto Layout]

Here you can see that my \$50 \Omega\$ termination resistor \$R2\$ is actually split into two resistors summing to \$51 \Omega\$, this is because I also want to scale the voltage down eventually, however I have tried this with a single \$50 \Omega\$ resistor directly across the transformer output with similar results. Additionally, I tried probing the output with a a scope probe, as well as sending it back into a coaxial cable to go directly to the scope (I tried it in 1M and 50 Ohm mode). I first tested this prototype with a function generator producing a 1.25 MHz sine wave and I got a perfect sine wave out(I also tried at 100kHz and up to 25Mhz with the same fidelity):

[image: Function Generator]

Unfortunately, when I tried to measure an actual ringdown signal, this was the best I could get:

[image: Actual Ringdown 1]

It seems that there are reflections on the coaxial cable causing the artifacts on the first quarter cycle. It does make sense to me that the actual ringdown contains many more (higher) frequency components than a simple sine wave from a function generator which, is probably why I am seeing these reflections only in the ringdown. However, I am surprised to see such bad reflections! The artifacts are minimized if I use a 1ft coaxial cable between the source and the transformer vs a 6ft or 10ft cable. However in the application the cable will need to be much longer. Probing with a scope probe resulted in massive ringing from the probe capacitance(I assume). The best signal (as seen above) was through a coaxial cable going to the scope in 50 Ohm mode.

My assumption is that if I had a perfect match at the transformer I would not see any reflections (or if the source was perfectly back matched, which it is not) therefore my simple \$50 \Omega\$ resistor is not properly matching the coaxial cable to my transformer for all the frequencies that it sees. I would like to get a second eye to confirm that I am on the right track, and hopefully someone has the experience to know how to better match the signal. I have already tried terminating the signal with a \$50 \Omega\$ resistor immediately on the board(placing it in parallel across the *input* of the transformer) to get the best match possible and then terminating the transformer with a ~1k resistor so that it does not present a significant load across the \$50 \Omega\$ resistor, but rather just "listens". This did not show significant improvement.

How can I best terminate this signal to minimize reflections?

Comment: Wow, you can see the reflections from very tiny parasitic's in that waveform, that's really cool!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the two series resistors on the output and how they correspond to your schematic. It looks like you are taking the output from the middle of the two termination resistors. Is that right? Shouldn't the output signal be from the *bottom* side of the right termination resistor?

Comment: Adding a series 50Ω between R1 and the cable should help prevent the reflections (stairway-like transients in the beginning of the waveform).

Comment: @joribama I have tried placing a 6dB attenuator at the output of the source to provide a back match but that didnt eliminate the reflections

Comment: @ReinstateMonica You are correct, to be true to the schematic the signal would be measured across both resistors (directly across the output of the transformer) however the layout pictured is the first I tried which also had a divider built in. Once I realized that the reflections were a problem I made several revisions trying to fix it and no longer have the divider in place.

Comment: A 6dB pad at the source should help, but not completely eliminate the reflection: when presented with low impedance on one side, the other side’s input impedance will be around 30 Ohms, not 50 Ohm. A higher attenuation pad (let’s say 30dB) will provide better matching at the cost of amplitude reduction. The simpler 50 Ohm series has no attenuation cost. Once the source is matched, the load will never see any reflection.

Comment: @joribama I see, I will look into implementing this! The source is in  it's own enclosure and just has a BNC output, I will have to figure out  how I can go about adding the resistor. Would a 1/4W through hole type resistor work or would it add a concerning amount of inductance?

Comment: I would start with a through hole resistor for convenience. If you notice that the parasitic inductance is a problem (we’re not dealing with super high frequencies here) then consider building a small PCB with an SMD resistor.

Comment: And just as a sanity check, make sure you’re using a 50 Ohm cable. If using a 75 Ohm cable instead, just use a 75 Ohm series resistor then

Comment: Let me rephrase something I said above... the series resistance source matching has no attenuation cost if the load is high impedance. In this case, with a 50Ω load, the signal will be attenuated by 6dB (R+R voltage divider). What brings us to something else you could try: remove the shunt 50Ω at the load once you have the series 50Ω at the source.